# How would I link together methods from different classes in java?

Tags: java, class, variables, methods

This is the code for one of the methods I wrote:

```
public void createReservation (String guestName, String roomType) {
  Reservation roomReservation;
  Room roomAvailability;
  roomAvailability = findAvailableRoom(hotelRooms, roomType);
  if(roomAvailability != null) {
  roomReservation = new Reservation(roomAvailability, guestName);
  }
  else {
    System.out.println("A room of this type is not available.");
  }
}
```

The error is coming from line 4. The error says that the symbol cannot be found. Although I think I know why, I am not entirely sure how to fix the problem.

findAvailableRoom is a method from a different class and I am trying to transfer it into this class. I thought that writing it like that would suffice but it doesn't seem to have worked.

This is the method that I am referring to. It is in a different class.

```
public Room findAvailableRoom (Room [] roomList, String desiredType) {
    for (int i = 0; i < roomList.length; i++) {
      if (roomList[i].getAvailability() == true && roomList[i].getType() == desiredType) {
      return roomList[i];
      }
  }
    return null;
  }
```

Any help?

Comment: Please share that class' source. Is this a static method? An instance method?

Comment: Yes, I have edited it just now. And I believe it is an instance method.

Comment: What class does it come from? You'd have to create an instance of that class in order to call its methods

Comment: I see. Would you know how I would create an instance of that class?

Comment: With the `new` operator, presumably.

Comment: I see. So instead, should I should write new findAvailableRoom(hotelRooms, roomType)? If so, that still doesn't seem to compile. The error message is the same. Should I mention the type of the method as well?

Comment: you need an instance of whatever class findAvailable rooms is in, let's say your class is RoomSearch... then you go RoomSearch rs -= new RoomSearch(); then rs.findAvailableRooms(...);  If its a static method, you don't need the instance and you can just type RoomSearch,findAvailableRooms(...);

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you're asking, you need an instance of the object of which field is needed. Another possibility is to make that field static.